# mamp attempts to download a file instead of displaying the webpage

Tags: mamp

Just did a fresh install of MAMP, and changed the apache path to go to /desktop/websites/mywebsite 
After starting the servers
When I go to localhost/mywebsite
It attempts to download a file instead of rendering the page. Its as if it doesnt know to look for the php file and render it. 
When I look at the file it downloads this is the contents.

```
bookmark88§ur¯oy ¿A –ApplicationsMAMPhtdocscryptoklout$0@D≈"Éo#Ö#l|åúA¿ NZ   file:///Macintosh HD`Fd:AºG[Õ$E36D512B-62C0-3BA1-816E-F5178841DA28ÅÔÔ/0dnibrdlfÃ˛ˇˇˇT¨‘@ƒ å ¸  @   0  l0 Ù–Ù–@"ò
```

What could I have done wrong here? Figured this would have worked right out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out, the website I was trying to view had a php error in it. MAMP does not display errors on the screen by default, you actually need to turn this on. I guess that is a security precaution in case you went live with a website or something. To resolve this you would need to go into the php.ini file and set
display_errors = On

I would think for a local server system like MAMP they would turn that on by default but whatevs.